# ASP.Net Framework 4.0 WCF Concurrency

Tags: wcf

I am new to WCF, I am facing concurrency related issue in my hosted wcf service (.net framework 4.0) on IIS 7 / Windows 2008 server. I did all the possibilities after googling but still not able to fix my problem. I have created and inventory service which uses Entity Framework to fetch data from SQL Server tables like `ItemHeadMaster`, `ItemMaster` etc.

I referenced this WCF in my custom user search control for searching purposes. All is running well when 2 concurrent user hit search control placed on ASP.Net page.

My code looks like this:

```
namespace HIS.STORESERVICES
{
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class StoreMasterData : IStoreMasterData
    {
 public string GetAllItemHead(string strHospitalId)
        {
            using (DAL.ItemHeadMaster objItemHeadMasterDAL = new DAL.ItemHeadMaster())
            {
                List<STORE.MODEL.ItemHeadMaster> objItemHeamMasterList = new List<STORE.MODEL.ItemHeadMaster>();
                objItemHeamMasterList = objItemHeadMasterDAL.GetAllItemHead(strHospitalId);
                XmlSerializer Xml_Serializer = new XmlSerializer(objItemHeamMasterList.GetType());
                StringWriter Writer = new StringWriter();
                Xml_Serializer.Serialize(Writer, objItemHeamMasterList);
                return Writer.ToString();
            }
        }
}
```

I did following after googling:

1. added in config but NO EFFECT

   ```
   <system.net>
       <connectionManagement>
           <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
       </connectionManagement>
   </system.net>`
   ```
2. Added in config but NO EFFECT instead it gets more slow..

   ```
   <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
             <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" 
                                maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" 
                                maxConcurrentSessions="20"/>
   ```

Please help

Comment: what problem did you have? performance or runtime errors?

Comment: performance problem, page almost hangs.

Comment: Why on earth are you manually XML serializing your data?? WCF will do this for you automatically. So basically you're XML serializing it first, and then WCF does it again..... Just return a `List<Something>` and let WCF do the work!

Comment: marc_s, thanks for quick reply, i m removing these xml serializing from code and will check the performance again.

Comment: thanks marc_s, after removing manual serialization it is performing fast, but now new problem started occur, when i invoke the service for the very first time it works fine when i access from client...
but later after 2 or 3 hits it gives me the Timeout Exception Pls suggest

Comment: Done!! i fixed Timeout problem!!Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before WCF, to construct a service for cross process communications between processes in the same host, or in the same LAN, or in the Internet, you have to hand-craft transportation layers and data serializations for target environments and specific protocols.

With WCF, you just need to focus on creating data models (DataContracts after being decorated by attributes) and operation models (OperationContracts), and .NET CLR will "create" most if not all needed transportation layers and data serializations at run time, according to the configuration defined by you or the system administration in the target environment.

The defects in your codes:

1. WCF typically uses DataContractSerializer, NOT Xmlserializer to serialize things, and you don't need to call it explicitly, since the runtime will do it.
2. For most applications, you don't need ServiceBehaviorAttribute explicitly. You must know WCF in depth before using those advantage config which is not for beginner. And I rarely used them.

Your service interface function should comfortably return complex type rather the serialized text. In 99.9% of cases, if you have explicit serialization codes in WCF programs, the whole design is very dirty if not entirely wrong.

There are plenty of tutorials of creating Hello World WCF projects, and VS has one for you when creating a new WCF application. After you got familiar with Hello World, you may have a look at  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627240/WCF-for-the-Real-World-Not-Hello-World

BTW, WCF serialization is very fast, check http://webandlife.blogspot.com.au/2014/05/performances-of-deep-cloning-and.html

Comment: thanks Andy, now performing fast but after 4-5 parallel hit it start giving timeout error "The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9990000. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout."

Comment: I am using wsHTTPBinding

Comment: Done!! i fixed Timeout problem!!Thanks

Comment: Have you removed [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]? you should, since by default the behavior is multithreading. The hit performance problem is likely related to the performance of call stacks, for example the data access layer, nothing to do with WCF. You might write a separated threaded test to see the concurrency performance of the other layers or tiers.

Comment: I removed [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple), removed  manual xml serialization, but it doesn't make much difference. u r right hit problem is likely related db calls, should i add Cache with SQLCacheDependency to reduce db hits??

Comment: Cache is only one of the methods to improve db calls performance, and should be the last resort. You may consider an overhaul of the design of the data access layer, and this is worth of a new subject/question.